# Show Toolbar in Youtube Activity (YouTubeBaseActivity)

Tags: java, android, youtube, toolbar

**This is my xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="16dp">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my VideosActivity**

```
public class VideosActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {}
```

**How to add Toolbar for this activity**

Answer (score 0):

> **This code only works in API level greater than 21**

**in you XML place Toolbar code**

```
 <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">

    </Toolbar>
```

**In you YouTubeBaseActivity  set The toolbar**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setActionBar(toolbar);
```